# Get specific data from Sharepoint list

Tags: list, filter, dropdown, data

I’m trying to get specific data from sharepoint list. I want user to select from drop down menu and depending selected value get row data from list matching values because i want to fill out particular text fields.  For example, drop down menu has many countries and I have a list with 3 columns (country, population, capital city). If user select country A then it shows on a text field population, and capital in other text field corresponding to that country. I know similar tasks can be done with casacading drop downs but this time I think is not the correct way. Hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance!!!!

FYI: I’m using Sharepoint 2016

Answer (score 1):

You could work with a linked list field that points to your country list. After that you can include the fields in the view to display them.

This is slightly different since you wont be able to update/edit the data.

Steps needed:

- Create the lookup list (LL) with 2-3 fields and fill it with data
- goto your main list and add another column of the Lookup type
- Point it to your LL list under "Additional Column Settings"
- select the fields you want to be visible in your list under "Additional Column Settings"
- save it so the column is added
- done

Comment: How I can do that? Do you have any steps or code to use it as a guide? Thanks again

Comment: added steps to the answer